# How to add a route?

Tags: windows, routing

How can I add a route from `10.35.0.0` to `10.10.10.0` with a mask `255.255.255.0` ?

I'm actually trying to access from 10.35.0.2 to 10.10.10.88 with 8080 port. Firewall is off on `10.10.10.88`.

I tried the following but no luck `10.35.0.250` is the gateway of `10.35.0.2`

`route add 10.10.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.35.0.250`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand your network setup better. I think you're a little confused about what a gateway or router is.

Most networks have a router. Your default gateway will be that router. The router should know the next-hop for each network (in this case `10.35.0.x` and `10.10.10.x`). So your client should be sending ALL outbound traffic to the router and it is the router that knows about the subnets.

Any routing commands should be reserved for the router (i.e. "gateway").

Comment: so do I have to configure/define subnets on `10.35.0.250` to hop on 10.10.10.0 ?

Comment: bwal grh mfft zbgsh? Let's go back a step. Can you draw your network explaining what the router is and whether you have access to configure that router? Who told you that you needed an explicit subnet route? What's your current routing tables looking like?